# Including the code of the html file in javascript. Using include

Tags: javascript, html, css, include, require

There is a page

[image: desiredview]

in which, depending on the selected menu item from the left column (Smartphones and gadgets, Laptops and computers, TVs, audio-video, Hi-Fi, Household appliances for home and kitchen, Construction and repair, House and cottage, Photo, video, systemssecurity, Auto goods, Stationery, Furniture and office equipment, Beauty and health), subcategories of the selected category on the left are displayed on the right side of the window.

I give the code

```js
document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.position = "fixed";
  document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginTop = "0";
  document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display = "block";
  console.log(document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.display);
  document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.marginRight = "20%";
  document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.width = "80%";
  document.getElementById('dropdownwindowright').style.flex = "60%";
  document.getElementById('dropdownwindow').style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
  const menuelems = document.querySelectorAll('.menulistitem');
  menuelems.forEach((menuelem) => {
    menuelem.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
      event.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
      event.target.classList.add('menulistitem_selected')
    });
    menuelem.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
      event.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
      event.target.classList.remove('menulistitem_selected')
    });
  });
```

```css
#dropdownwindow {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 5;
}

#fullblock {
  height: 100vh;
  position: static;
}

.contentdropdownwindow {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.CatalogMenuLeft {
  width: 25%;
}

.catalogheader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  /*display: flex;*/
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.crossline,
.bottompart {
  flex: 1;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*height: 33%;*/
}

.crosslineright {
  width: 100%;
  /*margin-top: 40px;*/
  /*margin-left: 20px;*/
  /*margin-right: 20px;*/
  /*align: right;*/
  text-align: right;
}

.windowheader {
  flex: 1;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*height: calc(100% - 2*37.5px);*/
  /*height: 34%;*/
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.windowheader h4 {
  flex: 1;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexdisabledscrollbar1,
.flexdisabledscrollbar2,
.flexdisabledscrollbar3 {
  flex: 0;
  width: 5px;
  border-right: 5px solid #f5f5f6;
}

.flexline1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 33%;
}

.flexline2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 34%;
}

.flexline3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 33%;
}

.flexcontent {
  display: flex;
  /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}

#menulist {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

.menulistitem {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/* Works on Firefox */

#menulist {
  scrollbar-width: auto;
  scrollbar-color: #b8b8bc #f5f5f6;
  /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
  /*height: 200px;*/
}


/* Works on Chrome, Edge, and Safari */

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f5f5f6;
}

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #b8b8bc;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  border: 0px solid #f5f5f6;
}

#menulist::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b8b8bc;
}

.menulistitem_selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menulistitem_selected::after {
  content: "\2192";
  /*position: absolute;*/
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: all .1s ease;
}

.close {
  margin-top: -14px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownwindowright {
  width: 75%;
}

.CatalogMenuSearch #SearchBlock {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid orange;*/
}

#SearchBlock {
  padding-top: 5px;
  /*padding-left: 25px;*/
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  /*padding-right: 50px;*/
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfe1;
}

#SearchInputdiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100%-35px);
  flex: 1;
  /*color: #dfdfe1;*/
  /*flex: calc(100%-35px);*/
}

#SearchInput {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#SearchButtondiv {
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 35px;
  /*flex: 35px;*/
}

#SearchButton button svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
  fill: #dfdfe1;
  /*justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 35px;*/
}

#SearchButton {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#SearchButton:active {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindow">
  <!-- <div class="crossline">
            <div class="close">&times;</div>
        </div> -->
  <div class="contentdropdownwindow">
    <div class="CatalogMenuLeft">
      <div class="catalogheader">
        <div class="flexline1">
          <div class="crossline">
          </div>
          <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar1">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flexline2">
          <div class="windowheader">
            <h4>Каталог</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flexline3">
          <div class="bottompart">
          </div>
          <div class="flexdisabledscrollbar3">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flexcontent">
        <div class="windowmenulist" id="menulist">
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Smartphonesandgadgets
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Ноутбуки и компьютеры
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Телевизоры, аудио-видео, Hi-Fi
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Бытовая техника для дома и кухни
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Строительство и ремонт
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Дом и дача
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Фото, видео, системы безопасности
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Автотовары
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Канцтовары, Мебель и Офисная техника
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Красота и здоровье
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Спорт и отдых
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Товары для геймеров
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Уцененные товары
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Подарочные сертификаты
          </div>
          <div class="menulistitem">
            Сервисы и услуги
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="myscroll">

    </div>
    <div id="dropdownwindowright">
      <div class="crosslineright">
        <div class="close">&times;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
        <div id="SearchBlock">
          <div id="SearchInputdiv">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по товарам" id="SearchInput">
          </div>
          <div id="SearchButtondiv">
            <button id="SearchButton"><svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path></svg></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<div>-->
  <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

There is a smartphonesandgadgets.html file and a commonstylesformenuitems.css (which should load when you hover over the left column menu item)

```css
.headercontent {
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.menucategoryitem {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.menucategoryitem .menu__item {
  padding: 0 20px 40px 0;
  max-width: 260px;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.menucategoryitem .menu__item .headersubmenu {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

.menucategoryitem .menu__item ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menucategoryitem .menu__item ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
}

/*.headersproductcategory {

}*/
```

```html
<h1 class="headercontent">Smartphonesandgadgets</h1>
  <div class="menucategoryitem">
    <div class="menu__item">
      <h2 class="headersubmenu">Заголовок</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <h2 class="headersubmenu">Заголовок</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <h2 class="headersubmenu">Заголовок</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <h2 class="headersubmenu">Заголовок</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <h2 class="headersubmenu">Заголовок</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <h2 class="headersubmenu">Заголовок</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <h2 class="headersubmenu">Заголовок</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
        <li>Смартфон</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It should be that on mouseover

```
            const menuelems=document.querySelectorAll('.menulistitem');
            menuelems.forEach((menuelem) => { menuelem.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => { event.target.style.cursor = "pointer";event.target.classList.add('menulistitem_selected')});
```

block

```
                <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
                </div>
```

was filled with the contents of the file `smartphonesandgadgets.html` (in the case of simply loading the page without hovering the mouse cursor over the menu item from the left column, the contents of the window for the menu item Smartphones and gadgets should open in the right part). How can this be done? Is such a construction possible

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('CatalogMenuRight')[0].innerHTML+=include('../html/smartphonesandgadgets.html');
```

?

Comment: Can you reduce the code in your question to a [mcve], please. There's too much to work with here, and it might help you to understand the issue better.

Comment: sounds to me that you trying to create a SPA (Single Page Application) which you do way to complicate. You dotn even need a script for it. You could hack that by using anchors and `:target` as pseudo selectors. Also dont use `getElementsbyClassName`. Use either `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @tacoshy What can be used instead of **include** in the design `document.getElementsByClassName('CatalogMenuRight')[0].innerHTML+=include('../html/smartphonesandgadgets.html');`
?